# Read product reviews and find better alternatives by scanning barcode

Tags: barcode

Is there a way to read product reviews and find alternative products/suggestions by scanning a barcode with my Galaxy Nexus? I found [searchreviews](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.searchreview), but it was not so good. If not, are there any web services to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ShopSavvy Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.biggu.shopsavvy&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmJpZ2d1LnNob3BzYXZ2eSJd) to scan barcodes and check for reviews. It works with Google books and other services. You can also let it search online; it will open your browser and search the barcode.

I'm not sure about alternatives, though. But if it takes you to Amazon, Amazon can give you recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

[Flow Powered by Amazon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a9.flow) can read barcodes, QR codes, and even does character recognition to read CD, DVD, and book titles, plus some other cool stuff. If you're very much into the Amazon.com ecosystem it's worth a look. ([Techcrunch write-up](http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/02/amazons-flow-app-brings-barcode-scanning-augmented-reality-to-android-users/))

[Amazon Price Check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.pricecheck) sticks to just doing Amazon.com price lookups.